# How do I sum all the numbers between the OR?

Tags: javascript

So I have an array

which is

```
 let arr = [[2, "OR", 22, 22, "OR", 22, 20], [300, "OR", 22, 300, "OR", 22, 22, "OR", 1], [1212, 2, "OR", 1]]
```

I want the array to summarize all the number between the "OR",

for example above, it would be

[[2,"OR",44, "OR", 42], [300, "OR", 322, "OR", 42, "OR", 1], [1214, "OR, 1]]

Been cracking my head for couple days I still can't find anything close to solving this.

Comment: This looks pretty easy to do. What have you tried?

Comment: Use the available [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods) methods (both static and on prototype).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.reduce()` and decide whether you are going to accumulate the current value to the previous one based on the position of "OR". The fact that you have an array of arrays, just means you'll have to repeat that same algorithm for all the sub arrays, for which you can use `.map()`:

```js
let arr = [[2, "OR", 22, 22, "OR", 22, 20], [300, "OR", 22, 300, "OR", 22, 22, "OR", 1], [1212, 2, "OR", 1]]

let res = arr.map(sub =>
    sub.reduce((acc, val, i) => {
        if (!i || [val, sub[i-1]].includes("OR")) acc.push(val);
        else acc[acc.length-1] += val;
        return acc;
    }, [])
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Oh wow, did not think of that. I was doing a lot of for loops and could not even get the same result. Thank you a bunch.